# Eloquent whereRaw statement and orWhereRaw is NULL

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

For a search query I have the following:

```
DB::whereRaw('column = ?', 'foo')->orWhereRaw('column IS NULL')->get();
```

Adding the `orWhereRaw` statement gives me less results than only the `whereRaw`. Somehow it seems to ignore the first when adding the other. It is included in the SQL statement. Is there another way to compare for a string and null value?

I have also tried the following, as suggested below:

```
return self::select('id')
    ->where('current_state', 'unavailable') 
    ->orWhereNull('current_state') 
    ->get();
```

If I change the order (the whereNull first and the where second) this also gives me different results. It appears as if the inclusive query doesn't function correctly in correspondence with the where clause. If I use to regular where clauses I don't experience any issues.

Running `SELECT * FROM events WHERE current_state='unavailable' OR current_state IS NULL;` does produce the correct result for me.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use whereRaw to check for null. You can use this instead:

```
->orWhereNull('column')
```

The proper way to do the first where, unless you're doing something extra such as a mysql function, is just to pass the column along like this:

```
where('column', '=', 'foo')
```

You can actually eliminate the equals, since it defaults to that. So your query would be:

```
DB::table('table')->where('column', 'foo')->orWhereNull('column')->get();
```

Comment: I agreed that you should use `whereNull` and `orWhereNull` but, your first `whereRaw` probably should be `where` as `whereRaw` doesn't accept that signature

Comment: This still gives me less results when adding the inclusive orWhereNull. 
return self::select('angel_id')
    ->where('current_state', 'unavailable')
    ->orWhereNull('current_state')
    ->get();
If I change the order (the whereNull first and the where second) this also gives me different results.

Comment: How odd. If you run the queries directly into mysql or a phpmyadmin interface, do you get the expected results?

Comment: See above, I tried running the SQL query and this does produce the results I need and expect.